# Append SKU in media images name

Tags: magento-1.9, php, product-images, media-images, image-url

I want to update each and every image name from product media gallery.

I want to append SKU in product name **for example imagename-SKU.jpg**

Any Idea how to append all existing images  using extensional php script ?

Comment: try https://github.com/Vinai/nicer-image-names

Comment: can we use for existing product image names ?

Comment: no you have to write script for that

Comment: yes what i mean to ask this question. @Gopal Patel